# Choosing next element without index

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying click on elements all elements with the link text edit by:

`for i in browser.find_elements_by_link_text('edit'):
     browser.find_element_by_link_text('edit').click()`

Now, this obviously only clicks on the first element found `i` times. I would usually try to use `XPath/CSS Selector` and loop using an index as you do with tables to get the next element, but these XPaths are identical other than having different ID's, so I don't know how to click on all elements in this case.

It's Reddit comments I try to edit:

[image]

With the XPaths:

```
//*[@id="e9sczhm"]/div[2]/div[2]/a[5]

//*[@id="e9s7x4j"]/div[2]/div[2]/a[5]
```

Comment: Post your HTML.

Comment: Update the question with text based _HTML_, your code trials and relevant error

Answer (score 0):

it should be `i.click()`

```
for i in browser.find_elements_by_link_text('edit'):
    i.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in browser.find_elements_by_link_text('edit'):
        browser.find_element_by_link_text('edit').click()
```

to

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# Find just one element
browser.find_element_by_link_text('edit').click() #<<<--- Starting point (cursor current position)
scheme = (Keys.TAB,Keys.Enter,Keys.TAB,Keys.TAB,Keys.Enter)
for i in scheme : browser.sendKeys(i)
```

**[Starting pos/elem][TAB][HIT][Element-1][TAB][Element-2][TAB][Element-3][TAB][HIT][Element-4]**

just hit first and fourth element !